# Dataset has no candidates for prophet add_regressor

Tags: categorical-encoding, prophet, exogeneity

I'm a student working with https://www.kaggle.com/aksha17/superstore-sales, primarily as an exercise in resampling and using prophet and it was suggested to me to create dummy variables and use the likes of 'Category' and 'Segment' as additional regressors to improve the 'Sales' forecast

And for the life of me, I can't see why I should as they are not independent and would merely separate the element values before adding back up to create 'Sales'.

I've separated them out, added the missing dates etc to create

```
        Order Date      Segment     Category          Sales
        8   2015-01-07  Consumer    Furniture         76.728
        9   2015-01-07  Consumer    Office Supplies   10.430
        10  2015-01-08  0           0                  0.000
        11  2015-01-09  Consumer    Office Supplies    9.344
        12  2015-01-09  Consumer    Technology        31.200
        13  2015-01-10  Corporate   Furniture         51.940
        14  2015-01-10  Corporate   Office Supplies    2.890
        15  2015-01-11  Consumer    Furniture          9.940
```

prior to splitting as dummies which I'd then need to re-sum to get back to one line per date for feeding into prophet
( and sum the dummies? or create compound variable from Segment+Category and then dummy on that? )

But all the time I think I'm on the very wrong path as these are not exogenous variables and should not be used as regressors

Your thoughts please

Comment: Why do you think the variables should not be used? I'd guess that there could be a difference between corporate vs consumer sales, or office supplies vs furniture, so accounting for it should improve the predictions.

Comment: "Additional regressors" in what context?  What are the current regressors?